# JAVA upload string to server

Tags: java, ftp

I would like to upload a string to a server in java. I would not like to just upload a file I would like to upload a string

```
String toupload = "Cheese"; Upload(toupload);
```

like this

Comment: ok,. what protocol is this server? http?

Comment: Yes the protocol is http @MeBigFatGuy

Comment: Why can't you post using usual http POST or pass it as query string in GET?

Comment: How would one do this? @kamoor1982

Comment: If your server supports http, that means you will be able create a servlet controller or JSP and read parameters from it. Try reading http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html

Comment: forgive me, i am a noob at java. How will this help me?

Comment: Use an HttpURLConnection, and produce a post with a message body having the string you want to send.

Comment: Im sorry maybe i should have phrased my question better. How do i upload a string to a server and store it in a text file

Answer (score 0):

You can upload it using both **POST** method, and **GET** methods:
    If you use the GET method:   **you pass the string in the url**.

ex: **localhost:8080/yourwebproject/yourservlet?nameofyourstring=itsvalue**

And then in your servlet you can do something like:

```
    public myServlet extends HttpServlet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
       public myServlet() {
            super();
        }
       /*This method will be called by your web-container if you used the get method..*/
       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        //here we go
        String str = request.getParameter("nameOfyourString");
       }`
}

If you use the POST method, you have to implement the doPost with same logic..
```